# What's the difference between 记录 and 纪录, both pronounced jìlù, and both meaning "record"?

Tags: difference

[记录](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%AE%B0%E5%BD%95) and [纪录](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BA%AA%E5%BD%95) are both pronounced the same, and mean "record".  It looks like both can be used as nouns and verbs.

**Question**: What's the difference between 记录 and 纪录?

I'm using [Zhongwen Chinese Popup Dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zhongwen-chinese-english/), and it says

> 纪录: variant of 记录 (but in Taiwan, not for the verb sense "to record")

I understand that to mean 记录 and 纪录 mean the same thing, where 记录 is the default, and 纪录 is a variant (except in Taiwan).  However, I'm not sure this is accurate.

Finding some examples online, we have...

1. **纪录**

   > 吉尼斯世界**纪录** ([source](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%90%89%E5%B0%BC%E6%96%AF%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E7%BA%AA%E5%BD%95))
   >   Guinness world **record**
   >
   > 破马拉松**纪录**奖励100万 ([source](http://sports.sina.com.cn/run/2019-12-17/doc-iihnzahi8061261.shtml))
   >   Break China's marathon **record** reward 1,000,000 [Chinese yuan]
2. **记录**

   > 幼儿教师观察**记录** ([source](http://www.yejs.com.cn/jswa/listmm/id/809.htm))
   >   Kindergarten teacher observation **records**
   >
   > 微信**记录**怎么彻底删除 ([source](http://www.chinaz.com/news/mt/2019/1217/1073718.shtml))
   >   How [do I] thoroughly delete Weixin **records**?

They do seem a bit different, but it's very unclear to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference: [写公文时如何区分“记录”与“纪录”](https://www.sohu.com/a/69966945_329045)

> 一、“记录”有动词和名词两种用法。

记录 could be used as verb and noun.

> 做动词的时候，表示把听到的、看到的或发生的事用文字、声音、影像等形式保留下来。例如：

When used as verb, means *to record what have been heard, what have been seen, or what happened in the form of text, voice, image etc*.

> （1）当时发生的情况我们已经记录在案了。
>
> （2）这份材料详细记录了这次会议的整个过程。
>
> （3）这段视频记录了几位优秀运动员日常的训练情况。
>
> 二、“记录”做名词的时候，有两个意思：

When used as noun,

> 1.表示记录下来的材料。例如：

refers to *materials being recorded*.

> （4）这份会议记录是保密的，已经放到保险箱里了。
>
> （5）这是侦查员勘查现场时作的现场记录。
>
> （6）今天上午，我先阅读一下有关记录，然后再作些分析。
>
> 2.表示作记录的人。例如：

refers to *who in charge of recording*.

> （7）局长让小刘担任会议记录。
>
> （8）我们推举他当记录。
>
> （9）马上开会了，你们谁是记录？
>
> 三、“纪录”是名词，表示在一定时期、一定范围内记载下来的最高成绩。例如：

纪录 is noun, means *the best record for a certain period of time and a certain scope*.

> （10）这个运动员在奥运会上创造了新的世界纪录。
>
> （11）炼钢厂昨天创造了日产量的新纪录。
>
> （12）这位试飞员在试飞中创造了该型飞机飞行速度的新纪录。
>
> 您提到的某杂志中说的“用镜头纪录身边的模范人物”，意思是用手机、照相机或录像机把身边模范人物的有关活动情景等“保留下来”，因此其中宜用“记录”，写成“用镜头记录身边的模范人物”。同类的例子再如：
>
> （13）他用日记记录了那些年在制药厂的生活。
>
> （14）这些照片记录了几十年前小村庄的旧貌。
>
> 而平时常说的“创造”“打破”之后，宜用“纪录”，说成“创造……纪录”“打破……纪录”。

After 创造 (make) and 打破 (break) 纪录 should be used.

> 过去，曾有“记录”跟“纪录”混用的情况，但是现在则明确区分了两者的用法。表示“最高”或“最好”成绩时，一般用“纪录”而不用“记录”。表示“保留下来”或“保留下来的材料”时，一般用“记录”而不用“纪录”。

When used for *the highest or best achievement*, 纪录 but not 记录 is used usually. When used for *keeping/recording or materials being recorded*, 记录 but not 纪录 is used usually.

> 杜永道
>
> （摘自《秘书工作》杂志2015年第9期）

Answer (score 4):

Both 记录 and 纪录 can be a noun for "record" or a verb for "to record"

> 紀 has the meaning of "historical record"; "epoch; period; age"

- 纪录(n) is more often used for "record" (of historical fact).  e.g. 目前男子一百米短跑世界[**紀錄**]为 9.58 秒; 多倫多最低氣溫[**紀錄**]是 −33 °C
- 纪录(v) is more often used for "to record" (historical item). e.g. "资治通鉴[**纪录**]了由公元前 403年 至 公元 959年的 1362 年歴史"
- 记录(n) is appropriate term for any information that's being recorded e.g. 查看通话[**记录**]
- 记录(v) applies to recorded information in general. e.g. 打卡机的功能是[**记录**]員工的上下班時間